# TKinter how to stop the mainloop while its running and return to "idle" state

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, raspberry-pi4

I have a tkinter application where user have many tasks to do. Most of the tasks call themselves recursively with tkinter after() method since every call I must check some pin states and other things, I figured that calling the function recursively every second will be fine. When the requirmenet is met ( some ping is toggled as required by the task), the task will complete and the function will go to mainloop "idle" state where I wait again for the user input.

Everything works fine except that I would like to implement one very important feature. Whenever user starts a task, I must have a emergency reset button, if pressed would restart the mainloop and immediately return to the "idle" state without the need to complete task. However, when the mainloop is running, I am not not sure how can I interrupt the task and stop it. I have made a simple "test" program to show exactly what I mean:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Button,Entry,Canvas,Label,ttk





class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,master=None):
        self.master = master
        self.button_counter = 0
    def Create_canvas(self,canvas_width,canvas_height):
        global canvas#described as global because used outside class
        canvas = tk.Canvas(master,bg='papaya whip',width=canvas_width,height=canvas_height)
       
    def Application_Intro(self):
        print("starting new app")
        restart_program_button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Restart_program",font='Helvetica 12 bold', width=20, height=2,
                                           command =self.Restart)
        start_program_button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Start_program",font='Helvetica 12 bold', width=20, height=2,
                                         command =self.Start_program)
        increment_button = tk.Button(canvas, text="increment_button",font='Helvetica 12 bold', width=20, height=2,
                                         command =self.increment_button)
        
        canvas.create_text(960,20,text="MY PROGRAM",font='Helvetica 16 bold')
        canvas.create_window(710,300,window = restart_program_button)
        canvas.create_window(710,500,window = start_program_button)
        canvas.create_window(710,100,window = increment_button)
        canvas.pack()
        master.mainloop()
        
    def increment_button(self):
        print("BUTTON INCREMENTED")
        self.button_counter = self.button_counter +1 # increment button pressed everytime is pressed
        
    def Start_program(self):
        print("Program started")
        if(self.button_counter > 1):
            print("Task complete")
            self.button_counter = 0
            return
        else:
            master.after(1000,self.Start_program)
        
    def Restart(self):# IF TASK STARTED SET RESTART =1, IF NOT restart devices and refresh app

        print("HERE I WANT TO INTERRUPT START PROGRAM AND RETURN TO IDLE STATE")
        print("REFRESH GUI ELEMENTS, DESTROY ANY WIDGETS IF CREATED")
        print("RESET THE GLOBAL VARIABLE VALUES")

        #master.mainloop()
        #WHAT TO DO IN THIS FUNCTION TO GO BACK TO INITIAL MAINLOOP STATE??
        return



master = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=master)
app.Create_canvas(1920,1080)

app.Application_Intro()
```

The program above will create a simple tkinter program with 3 buttons.

Button at the top will increment button counter variable

Button in the middle is supposed to interrupt whatever task is running and return to "idle"state immediately

Button at the bottom will start a task. A task involves a person pressing Button at the top 2 times to increment button counter >1. After button incremented the counter 2 times, i return out of the recursive function which returns me back to mainloop "idle" state.

Now, as I mentioned, I must implement a technique where a user can return to "idle" state of the mainloop even if he didint press button to increment counter. It may be due to whatever emergency reason but I must be able to stop the current task and cancel it!

Can someone suggest me how should I do that since I could not find a neat way to do that.. It is also very important for me that this "reset" function will work for any possible task.

For example in reset function I could just set the button counter to any values > 1, and then the next call to task would trigger a reset, but this may not be the case for other tasks I will have that will not have any button counter involved.

Appreciate any help and suggestions

Comment: You can use `.after_cancel(task_id)` to cancel the `after` task where `task_id` is the ID returned by `.after(...)`.

Comment: Thats cool suggestion. I was not aware of this after_cancel method.I guess I have to assign a variable to after method and then use that variable in after_cancel method. The only issue I see is how do my restart function keep track which task to cancel? Lets say I have 10 tasks and each one have assigned different names during after method, how would my restart function know which one to close?

Comment: It should be you to determine which task to close as it is your design.